# How to make a transparent status bar in Android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I want to make a transparent status bar in my application in Android 4.4.
How do I do that?

I tired:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/skipPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/skipPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/skipPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

and in the manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

and in the activity:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.StartActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```

Comment: Please take more care with your spelling and your grammar. If your post is hard to read because your English is terrible you won't get any answers.

Comment: Simple answer : Not possible , however you can change color of status bar in 4.4 only using SystemBarTint (Library is found on github).

Answer (score 0):

This one will throw exception on Lollipop devices. primColor must be opaque.

```
<item name="primColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Style your actionbar using `style.xml`

```
<style name="ThemeActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@null</item>
</style>
```

Include you theme..

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is set the status bar a darker shade of your background or even the same color by setting it in your activity.

You can set the status bar color in your activity with the following code `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));`.

If you want to use a darker shade of your color you can do it by changing your color's HSB. For a more detailed way of doing that you can read this post: [Android change status bar color by converting existing color's HSB](http://programminglife.io/android-change-status-bar-color-by-converting-existing-color-hsb/)