# Status bar transparency doesn't work

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-statusbar

I am trying to make status bar transparent in my application using this code:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But it doesn't work. Status bar just change a color and became grey, not transparent. Where is my mistake? How to make status bar transparent?

Comment: You can maybe check one of my previous answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33986302/3426717

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your `styles.xml(v21)`

```
<name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

**Update**

You can achieve the same effect programatically on KitKat and afterwards by setting this Window flag

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```

If you set a background resource (like a color or a picture) to your layout, you will see the color or picture "below" the status bar.

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/1549700)

Comment: Tests are being conducted on devices +19? What's the final result using this solution?

Comment: Yes, Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.1. Status bar became grey, but not transparent.

Comment: With `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);` it works. Thank you!

Comment: What's the reason for those flags not working? Any ideas?